# Error in program , count Inversions! What's the bug?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to write a simple program to count inversions in a vector. An inversion is simply the number of counts in a vector A where A[j] < A[i] such that i

I chose vectors since I am going to be reading values from a text file and vectors allow dynamic size. Following is my code:

```
using namespace std ;

int MergeAndCountSplitInv(vector<int> a ,const int low , const int mid ,const int high){

    cout << "Low " <<low << " mid " <<mid << " high " <<high << endl;

    for(int i = low; i<= high ;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" " ;
    }

    cout <<endl;
    int b[high - low + 1];
    int leftArrayIndex = low;
    int rightArrayIndex = mid + 1;
    int bIndex = low;
    int inversions = 0;

    while( (leftArrayIndex <= mid) && (rightArrayIndex <= high) ){
        if( a[leftArrayIndex] <= a[rightArrayIndex] ){
            b[bIndex] = a[leftArrayIndex];
            bIndex++;
            leftArrayIndex++;
        }
        else{
            b[bIndex] = a[rightArrayIndex];
            bIndex++;
            rightArrayIndex++;
            inversions += mid - leftArrayIndex + 1;
        }
    }

    while(leftArrayIndex <= mid){
        b[bIndex] = a[leftArrayIndex];
        bIndex++;
        leftArrayIndex++;
    }

    while(rightArrayIndex <= high){
        b[bIndex] = a[rightArrayIndex];
        bIndex++;
        rightArrayIndex++;
    }

    for(int i = low; i<=high ; i++){
        a[i] = b[i];
    }

    cout <<"inversions " << inversions<< endl ;
    cout <<"Exiting"<<endl;
    return inversions ;
}

// This function calculates the inversions present in the vector suppiled to it as input
int SortAndCount( vector<int> &a ,const int low ,const int high){
    // Remember that I use all indices as inclusive
    cout <<"Low : " << low << "   high : " << high <<endl ;
    int x , y , z, mid ;
    if(high > low){
        mid = (low + high)/2 ;
        x = SortAndCount(a , low , mid);
        y = SortAndCount(a , mid+1 , high);
        z = MergeAndCountSplitInv(a , low , mid , high);

    }
    else{
        cout << "Low >= High"<<endl;
        return 0; // This is the base case when the input size of the vector is one
    }

    cout <<"Returning"<<endl;
    return x+y+z;
}

int main()
{

 vector<int> Tester = {0,10,200,30,4,5,1,2,3,6,9,4000};

    int inversions = SortAndCount(Tester ,0 , 9);

    std::cout<<"Number of inversions in the Vector are " <<inversions<<endl;




}
```

It runs fine at times for a small size and then all of a sudden crashes. Can somebody please tell me what am i doing wrong here, I have been trying for hours not to debug it but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: such that i<j ( continuation of condition above).

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger to see at which line it crashes?

Comment: I have but I am not able to figure out why its crashing. The last thing it prints is 'Exiting' which means its exiting the function MergeAndCountSplitInv. Also, it works for some sizes of vector and doesn't for some other sizes.

Comment: you're passing `a` by value: `vector<int> a`... is that what you wanted? I see you're copying to it local  `b`- that has no effect outside of  `MergeAndCountSplitInv`

Comment: Yeah I changed that to passing by reference, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'int bIndex = low;' should be 'int bIndex = 0;'

Comment: You sir are right! Had to change the copying step too -                           for(int i = low; i<=high ; i++){
        a[i] = b[i-low];
    }